# Entity Framework .net core. На каком объеме строк в базе данных он начнет подтормаживать?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Вопрос к тем кто пользовался EF на больших базах данных. Если я добавлю одно обновление которое сейчас готовится, моя база может разрастись до 58 миллионов или более строк в одной из таблиц. Подскажите будет ли справляться с подобной базой EF? Или лучше уже начинать думать в сторону ADO.Net где можно руками оптимизировать SQL запросы ?

Вообще до какого объема записей в базе можно безболезненно использовать EF?

Comment: Мне кажется тут надо оптимизировать не запросы и базу, а то, как Вы взаимодействуете с этими данными. EF ленива, она не будет вам грузить все данные, если ее не попросить это сделать. То есть, если Вы делаете `var result = db.Table.Where(x=>x.IsTrue);`, то вам EF не загрузит все 58 миллионов в память, а вот если Вы напишете, к примеру `.ToList()`, то вот вам и все данные из базы в памяти. Так что, я не думаю, что проблема тут в EF будет.

Comment: Производительность LINQ-запросов EF, как и производительность SQL-запросов ADO.NET не зависит напрямую от количества строк. Есть зависимость от сложности запросов: наличие join'ов и т. п.

Comment: Если вы не выгружаете эти миллионы строк в память и у вас индексы на таблицах расставлены как надо, то EF вообще без разницы, столько строк у вас в БД.

Comment: Если БД правильно спроектирована, то любой нормальный ORM, включая EF, не будет испытывать проблем, если его нормально по гайдам использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если это простой SELECT без сложных JOIN'ов, то можно использовать Entity Framework даже для больших объёмов данных. В EF Core 5.0 появился метод ToQueryString (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-5.0), который превращает IQueryable в соответствующий SQL-запрос, всегда можно проверить, какой запрос составляет EF.
Также, если это запрос для чтения, то для ускорения можно пользоваться методом AsNoTracking для отключения change tracking на выбираемых сущностях (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-5.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

EF Core 3.1 свыше 100_000_000_000 записей в одной таблице PostgreSQL (8 полей, 1 ключевое, 2 индекса) - полёт отличный, пишется телеметрия по over 10_000 записей в секунду на HDD Seagate ST2000DM008 и при этом связанные значения выдёргиваются за какие-то доли секунд через индексы в кол-ве тысяч записей.

EF Core надёжная вещь, ничего на опережение делать не приходилось, а если и были где-то проблемы, самим EF Cor'ом они и решались.  Единственное что возникала проблема читать последнее значение по каждому связанному FK. Но в EF Core 5 кажется это исправили.